# Trigger Macro with Slicer Change (Table Slicers)

Tags: excel, vba, slicers

I would like to trigger some macros on clicking on a Slicer that was created based on a named table (Not a pivot table).

I tried right click - Assign macro, and this does work, but this also cancels the slicer actions, and I want to add to the slicer action, not cancel and replace it.

Is there any way to do this?

Comment: Assigning a macro to a sclicer does not disable the slicer actions but it is now more cumbersome to use it. You can select the slicer with pressed Ctrl key. Then the slicer will work. But IMO that is not very practical.

Comment: I found a workaround, using ```Private Sub Workbook_SheetCalculate(ByVal sh As Object)``` as a trigger works, but there is no way to pin point which slicer you triggered, if you have multiple on the same sheet.

Comment: Maybe If you use `Private Sub Worksheet_PivotTableUpdate(ByVal Target As PivotTable)`, you can tell the name of the pivot-table which connected to the slicer. Something like : `Application.EnableEvents = False: If Target.Name = "ThePivotTableNameWhichConnectedToTheSlicer" Then MsgBox "":Application.EnableEvents = true:end sub`. If you have two slicers where each connected to different pivot-table with different pivot-table data source, then I think you need to make a case.